# Checklist facet filter is not showing values

Tags: sxa

Need some clarification on Checklist filter in Sitecore `SXA`.

I have a field in a template where the type is `droplist`. Using this field as one of the filters facet in search.

I have added the field to index for the `facets` to appear.
Now when i create a checklist filter and use this field its not showing the facets, where as if i create a `dropdown` filter use the same field the facets are loading.

Is it like the checklist filter will work only with fields of type checklist ?

Comment: Did you check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13900/sxa-filter-checklist-not-working-with-facets-sxatags?rq=1?

Comment: ya did check the link, in our case the field type is droplist